# How to Access local RESTApi in Android Application

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, android-studio, android-webservice

I want access RESTApi which is already created in Microsoft .net 2012 to my android application.

But the problem is, when i run my Microsoft .net Application gives me url like

http://localhost:xxxx

which is actually not accesible in android application, android application needs specific Ip Address, like.

http://172.168.0.1:xxxx

so, what to do now?

Comment: Are you using Genymotion?

Answer (score 0):

To use localhost Run the emulator.
Or search for 'IP address' on Google ,  Android device and  PC use wi-fi .

Comment: Yes, jihnoon kim, i am using emulator but emulator doesn't use localhost, it is actually using IP Address